# How to implement static_cast in C++

Tags: c++, gmp, eigen, static-cast

I am trying to use the GMP number library together with Eigen matrix library. I try to instantiate the template:

```
Matrix<typename Scalar, int RowsAtCompileTime, int ColsAtCompileTime>
```

with

```
Matrix<mpz_class, 3, 3> matrix;
```

where mpz_class is a number class from the GMP library.

I get a compiler error:

```
 /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h:409: error: 
 invalid static_cast from     
 type ‘const __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>’ 
 to type ‘int’
```

When I examine the source code of the Eigen library, I find out, that the problem is that 
mpz_class cannot be static_cast -ed to int in this template:

```
template<typename OldType, typename NewType>
struct cast_impl
{
  static inline NewType run(const OldType& x)
  {
    return static_cast<NewType>(x);
  }
};
```

How can I bypass this problem? I know how to convert mpz_class to int in runtime, but it must be done by the compiler, since static_cast is compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `mpz_class` is safe to subclass, you can just use a subclass and write a conversion operator:

```
class your_mpz_class : public mpz_class
{
public:

  // Write public constructors as needed

  operator int()
  {
    return /* Whatever must be returned */;
  }
};
```

Comment: You mean subclass mpz_class and add this operator int() ?

Comment: Ah, that would be a good solution, indeed. Assuming it is safe to subclass `mpz_class`, of course.

Comment: Now you need to check whether everything works as expected. Without knowledge of what is the use for that function, it is difficult to foresee.

Comment: Kleist's answer below is the right thing to do. Adding a wrapper class  is an ugly kludge.

Answer (score 7):

If you know how to implement it you can make a specialization of the `cast_impl` template class.

```
template <>
struct cast_impl<Type1, Typ2>
{
    static inline Type2 run(const Type1&x) {
        // Conversion here returning Type2 from Type1
    }
}
```

Type1 and Type 2 should be replaced with the actual types in your situation.

Comment: Assuming that `cast_impl` only contains the `run()` function, this solution looks better than mine in this specific case. Of course, it might also be that OP just indicated the relevant function and skipped the rest of the class, I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers you may want to read "[Eigen: Using custom scalar types](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html#user_defined_scalars)" for other requirements of using a custom scalar class which you are likely to hit at some point.

Comment: Thank you! I am hitting errors one by one. I guess it is a good idea to read this first.